# Is it possible to rearrange $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \prod_{k=0}^{k=i-1}\frac{(A+kB)}{i!C}\pi_0 = 1$ for $\pi_0$?

Tags: summation, gamma-function, products

I solved the detailed balance equation subject to $\sum \pi_i=1$ and $\pi_i>0$ to get:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \prod_{k=0}^{k=i-1}\frac{(A+kB)}{i!C}\pi_0 = 1$$

I'm having a tough time rearranging for $\pi_0$.

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \prod_{k=0}^{k=i-1}\frac{(A+kB)}{i!C}\pi_0 = 1$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{\pi_0}{\Gamma(i+1)C}\bigg)^i \prod_{k=0}^{k=i-1}(A+kB) = 1$$

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I do not precisely understand your question. What are $A,B$ and $C$? Is $\pi_0$ any variable? What kind of expression are you aiming for? Is the equation on the title the only constraint you have on $A,B,C$ and $\pi_0$?

Comment: what happens if $i=0$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I guess that the empty product has to be considered as $1$, then the term becomes $\frac{\pi_0}{C}$.

Comment: Correction: The $i=0$ term becomes $= 1$, after all: $x^0=1$.This allows one to obtain $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\pi_0^i}{(\Gamma(i+1)C)^i}\prod_{k=0}^{i-1} (A+kB) = 0$, or $\frac{\pi_0A}{C} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\dots\right) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to

$$ \sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{A}{B}+i\right)}{\Gamma(i+1)\Gamma(i-1) }\left(\frac{B\pi_0}{C}\right)^i  = \frac{B}{A} $$
or to
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{A}{B}+2\right)\,\phantom{}_1 F_1\left(2+\frac{A}{B};3;\frac{B\pi_0}{C}\right)=\frac{2C^2}{AB\pi_0^2} $$
that is a trascendental equation involving a hypergeometric function. An approximate solution can be found by exploiting [Gauss' continued fraction representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction) for $\phantom{}_1 F_1$, by exploiting Newton's method or through a combination of these approaches. I guess the right person to speak about this problem is Claude Leibovici, due to his experience in the field.

Comment: Thanks, this should be enough for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

Considering Jack D'Aurizio's answer, and replacing for clarity $$\frac{B\pi_0}C=x\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac AB =a$$  we then need to look for the zero(s) of the function 
$$f(x)=\Gamma (a+2) \, _1F_1(a+2;3;x)-\frac{2}{a x^2}$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3} (a+2) \Gamma (a+2) \, _1F_1(a+3;4;x)+\frac{4}{a x^3}$$ So, the iterates of Newton method will be given by 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n \left(1+\frac{6-3\, a\, x_n^2\, \Gamma (a+2) \, \, _1F_1(a+2;3;x_n)}{12+a\, x_n^3 \,\Gamma (a+3) \,\,
   _1F_1(a+3;4;x_n)}\right)$$ which should not make any problem provided whe have an $x_0$ to start iterating. This is addressed in the edits of the post.

Since the problem as been reduced to a single parameter $a$, here are the results for a few values of the numerical solutions.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & x \\
 0.1 & 2.03963 \\
 0.2 & 1.61757 \\
 0.3 & 1.38098 \\
 0.4 & 1.21673 \\
 0.5 & 1.09081 \\
 0.6 & 0.98855 \\
 0.7 & 0.90237 \\
 0.8 & 0.82783 \\
 0.9 & 0.76215 \\
 1.0 & 0.70347 \\
 1.1 & 0.65049 \\
 1.2 & 0.60228 \\
 1.3 & 0.55813 \\
 1.4 & 0.51750 \\
 1.5 & 0.47996 \\
 1.6 & 0.44519 \\
 1.7 & 0.41290 \\
 1.8 & 0.38286 \\
 1.9 & 0.35488 \\
 2.0 & 0.32881 \\
 2.1 & 0.30449 \\
 2.2 & 0.28179 \\
 2.3 & 0.26062 \\
 2.4 & 0.24087 \\
 2.5 & 0.22244 \\
 2.6 & 0.20527 \\
 2.7 & 0.18926 \\
 2.8 & 0.17436 \\
 2.9 & 0.16049 \\
 3.0 & 0.14759
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

In order to start iterating Newton method, developing $f(x)$ as a very limited Taylor series around $x=0$, we have $$f(x)=-\frac{2}{a x^2}+\Gamma (a+2)+O\left(x\right)$$ which gives as a good starting point $$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a\, \Gamma (a+2)}}$$

To show how Newton method works, consider the case $a=0.1$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 4.37168 \\
 1 & 3.25558 \\
 2 & 2.32495 \\
 3 & 2.03370 \\
 4 & 2.03963 
\end{array}
\right)$$ Now, for $a=3$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.166667 \\
 1 & 0.144357 \\
 2 & 0.147498 \\
 3 & 0.147592 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Working with Padé approximants, for $a>0.2$, a much better starting guess is $$x_0=6\frac{ 2a+4-\sqrt{6} \sqrt{-a^2-3 a+12 a \Gamma (a+2)-2}}{5 a^2+17
   a-36 a \Gamma (a+2)+14}$$

Working the range $0.1\leq a \leq 10$, the following curve fit gives very good estimates $$x=\frac{1.2417}{a^{0.293448} \Gamma (a+2.54785)^{0.449602}}$$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 A & 1.24170 & 0.02425 & \{1.19356,1.28984\} \\
 B & 0.29345 & 0.00209 & \{0.28930,0.29759\} \\
 C & 2.54785 & 0.04830 & \{2.45197,2.64373\} \\
 D & 0.44960 & 0.00378 & \{0.44211,0.45710\} \\
\end{array}$$

For $a=0.1$, this would give $x_0=2.04435$; for $a=3$, this would give $x_0=0.146591$.

Comment: (+1) This is exactly the masterful answer I was expecting from you :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. *Masterful* is really too much but thanks for the appreciation. I must confess that I cannot resist an equation as soon as numerical methods are to be used.